# Can't find variable azure mobile apps

Tags: javascript, azure, authentication, azure-mobile-services

In this [tutorial](https://shellmonger.com/2016/04/08/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-5-custom-authentication/) by Adrian Hall I got to the part where adds this code to the server. He says he added it to the initialization of azure mobile apps sdk. I have no idea where to find this and put it. I ended up putting it in my javascript file but this returns no azuremobileapps (obviously). So where do I put this code? I am new to this thanks in advance.

```
// Configuration of the Azure Mobile Apps can be done via an object, the
// environment or an auxiliary file.  For more information, see
// http://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-apps-node/global.html#configuration
var mobileApp = azureMobileApps({
    // Explicitly enable the Azure Mobile Apps home page
    homePage: true,
    // Explicitly enable swagger support. UI support is enabled by
    // installing the swagger-ui npm module.
    swagger: true,
    // Authentication settings for custom auth
    auth: {
        audience: '04pHmxVuhYU1QTDo4lEojLo1sseRLfKG',
        issuer: 'https://shellmonger.auth0.com'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I found it. It's in your script on the azure portal in the app.js under wwwroot.